# Angular 2: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check

Tags: angular, cors

I'm getting a very strange error on my Angular 2 app:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.ebay.com/ws/api.dll. Response
>   to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

The annoying thing is that I DO have that header in place:

```
headers.append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', "GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS")
headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', "Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token")
```

Screenshot for Charles Proxy:
[image]

Comment: The headers need to be added by the response you get from the server. Adding them on the request is useless. See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: What's the work around? I obviously don't work at eBay and cannot change their headers

Comment: Don't access an API that is not supposed to be used this way ;-) You can try `JsonpModule` instead of `HttpModule`, but this approach has some limitations (no custom headers can be sent). Another approach is to run your own server that forwards requests to the Ebay server and responses to the browser.

Comment: One general work around is to either set up your own CORS proxy or else replace the request URL with a URL the requests it through an open proxy, like this: https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.ebay.com/ws/api.dll

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution that I liked using a proxy server here:

[Configure a proxy for your API calls with Angular CLI](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OjmZPPKaj6A)

Comment: just adding the actual url in case  the serach results changes https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OjmZPPKaj6A